# XSTREAM array converter

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I want to convert below XML to objects. I

```
<authentication>
    <name>Reese Rideout</name>
    <shows type="array">
        <show>stage</show>
        <show>youtube</show>
    </shows>
</authentication>
```

I have Authentication class with List<Show> shows. I believe I will need to use the array converter. However, I do not understand how to use it and am not finding any documents.

Kindly suggest how could I parse this into my object graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I fixed this:

```
xstream.alias("shows", Shows.class);
xstream.alias("show", String.class);
```

And also set the `Shows.shows` field as an implicit collection: `xstream.addImplicitCollection(Shows.class, "shows");`

Comment: I'm not totally understanding your answer.  Can you give more detail like Jigar Joshi did?  What is the context of using .addImplicitCollection ?

Answer (score 2):

For

```
 <authentication>
      <name>Reese Rideout</name>
      <shows type="array">
         <show>stage</show>
         <show>youtube</show>
       </shows>
    </authenticatoin>
```

you can have

```
class Authentication{
String name;
List<Show> shows;
}

class Show{
List<String> show;
}
```

You will have to use [aliasing](http://xstream.codehaus.org/alias-tutorial.html)

```
xstream.alias("authentication", Authentication.class);
xstream.alias("Show", Show.class);
```

Comment: @Jinesh it can be , but from the XML you have given there is no need to take it as Object , String will do it for you

Comment: That did not work. the alias that i am configuring is     xstream.aliasField("show", Show.class, "show");

Comment: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: show : show
---- Debugging information ----
message             : show : show